# How can I save part of a string in an alias using Cypress?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, cypress

I'm trying to save just a number from a string I get from a paragraph but when I try to asign an alias to it and then check the value it returns undefined. I've tried a few solutions I found but none of those seem to work for me. These are two ways I tried (I tried another one similar to the second one but using split, had same result). The console.log inside of the 'then' doesn't show in the console, and when I try the alias after the code is when I get undefined.

```
    cy.get('p')
      .eq(1)
      .should('have.text', '/[0-9]+/g')
      .as('solNumber')

    cy.get('p')
      .eq(1)
      .invoke('text')
      .then((text)=>{
        var fullText = text;
        var pattern = /[0-9]+/g;
        var number = fullText.match(pattern);
        console.log(number);
      })
      .as('solNumber')
```

Answer (score 2):

Please convert with `+` operator and return the numeric value if you want numeric type to be stored.

```js
cy.get('p').eq(1)
  .invoke('text')
  .then(fullText => {
    const number = fullText.match(/[0-9]+/);
    return +number     // text to numeric
  })
  .as('solNumber')

cy.get('@solNumber')
  .should('eq', 42)    // numeric type
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Running your 2nd code on this,

```html
<p>21</p>
<p>42</p>
```

gives the correct outcome

```js
cy.get('p')
  .eq(1)
  .invoke('text')
  .then((text)=>{
    var fullText = text;
    var pattern = /[0-9]+/g;
    var number = fullText.match(pattern);
    console.log(number);                    // logs 42
  })
  .as('solNumber')

cy.get('@solNumber')
  .should('eq', '42')                       // passes
```

So, you need to inspect the DOM, it looks like it's not what you expect.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I checked and the yielded text was the correct one, still wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

The first attempt you were passing a jquery element to the `.should()` and although some chainers [change the subject](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should#Yields) yours did not so it saved the jquery element as `solNumber`.

The second attempt invokes the `.text()` which was passed to the `.then()` it logs the `number` correctly. However, you did not [return](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/then#Change-subject) anything at the end of the `.then()` block, therefore, `solNumber` should hold the entire paragraph.

This should help you out to extract the specific number and save it as an alias.

```
cy.get('p')
  .invoke('text')
  .invoke('trim')
  .then(paragraph => {
        const matcher = /some/
        expect(paragraph).to.match(matcher) // check number is there

        const indexOfText = paragraph.match(matcher) // get index of match text
        return paragraph.substring(indexOfText.index, indexOfText.index + indexOfText[0].length) // return substring
   })
  .as('savedText')

cy.get('@savedText')
  .then(cy.log) // will print out the number you seek
```